# Starting a ASP.NET MVC3 project in MonoDevelop? Steps to do so?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, mono, monodevelop

I'm using MonoDevelop on the Mac with the latest Mono version installed.

What steps do I need to take to start using MVC3 in a project with RAZOR syntax (.cshtml files)?

I've read http://www.mono-project.com/Release_Notes_Mono_2.10#ASP.NET_MVC3_Support but it doesn't spell it out. How do I create my first .cshtml file? How do I tell my application to point to Index.cshtml, and not the default Index.aspx file when creating an MVC (2) project in MonoDevelop?

---

**Update**

I started a new MVC2 project in Mono. I started a new MVC3 project in VS 2010. I copied all the required DLLs over from the MVC3 to the MVC2 project in Mono. Now I build and get a "The compiler has appeared to crash" in Mono.

[image: Error when building]

I thought there was MVC3 support? http://mono-project.com/Release_Notes_Mono_2.10#ASP.NET_MVC3_Support What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The MD ASP.NET MVC addin doesn't have explicit support for anything newer than ASP.NET MVC 1.0, but MD core has solid .NET 4.0 support so it should be possible to patch things together. Look at the build output to see the compiler crash trace, it might be something simple like a missing reference.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure how deep you're diving into Mono or what enviroment you're using, but here are three pretty useful blog articles about using MVC and Mono:

- [Get MVC3 Razor Running on Mono](http://www.integratedwebsystems.com/2011/06/get-mvc3-razor-running-on-mono/)
- [Setting up Mono 2.8 with Asp.Net 4.0 and MVC2 on Ubuntu with MySql
  Membership](http://www.integratedwebsystems.com/2010/11/setting-up-mono-2-8-with-asp-net-4-0-and-mvc2-on-ubuntu-with-mysql-membership/)
- [Installing OpenSuse 11.2 with Mono 2.6.1 and Apache Using Text Mode Configuration – Porting to Mono](http://www.integratedwebsystems.com/2010/01/installing-opensuse-11-2-with-mono-2-6-1-and-apache-using-text-mode-configuration-porting-to-mono-part-1-of-3/#RunningMVC)

The second link has a downloadable MVC application that has already been setup to run with a version of Mono and uses MySql with the membership provider scheme scripted into it.

I hope these links help you, and good luck with your project.

Comment: I'm on a Mac, running locally right now. I updated my question. Hoping someone can show me how to get this working.

Answer (score 4):

If you are getting the "Compiler has appeared to crash" when trying to cut over to MVC3, you should set your project to .NET 4. You can do this by right clicking on the project->Options->Build->General and selecting Mono / .NET 4.

Answer (score 3):

[This gentleman](http://blog.bennymichielsen.be/2011/05/14/mvc3-and-monodevelop/) seems to have had some success in getting MVC3 running in monodevelop on a mac.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get MVC3 and razor to work in xamarin studio on MacOS by following the solution here:

[Monodevelop MVC3 razor - what is the trick to get it to work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12849340/monodevelop-mvc3-razor-what-is-the-trick-to-get-it-to-work)