# Monodevelop MVC3 razor - what is the trick to get it to work?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, macos, mono, monodevelop

I use monodevelop 3.0.4.7 and mono 2.11.4 on mac OS 10.8.

When I create a new solution from scratch in monodevelop I can create several types of ASP.NET mvc3 projects with razor views, but the projects get created with references to system.web.helpers and system.web.webpages that are "not available for Mono/.net 4.0 in mono 2.11.4" and won't build.

If I change my .net version to 4.5 in the project options I get the system.web.webpages reference resolved, and if I simply remove the reference to system.web.helpers I am able to build the default site. However, it is unable to make use of .cshtml views, it only looks for aspx views.

I have tried different things related to references and versions of mono, changing the viewengine to razor in global.asax.cs and even copied dll's from a windows-based asp.net mvc application, but something new breaks all the time.

It seems strange that there are project types included that don't work from scratch, so I'm guessing/hoping I'm missing something much simpler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I happened across a solution for this issue here:

http://blog.miraclespain.com/archive/2013/Jun-24.html

Basically in xamarin studio you can *add a version of nuget* from the following add-in repository source:

http://mrward.github.com/monodevelop-nuget-addin-repository/4.0/main.mrep

Once nuget is installed, you can create a new mvc3 razor project, notice the missing references for system.web.helpers and system.web.pages and just remove them, then use nuget to add the *microsoft aspnet web pages 2* package which solves the missing references.

Comment: The link seems to be dead.

Answer (score 3):

I was sitting with the exact same problem, on Linux though, so I decided to ask on the mono mailing list (see the answer to my question here: http://lists.ximian.com/pipermail/mono-list/2012-October/049022.html).

The short answer is: no, you're not missing anything simple.

Long version: The current version of mono is not compiling the System.Web.Helpers.dll, so you have to do some footwork your self, to get it compiled. That is described in the link above.

I guess we just have to wait a little longer before this becomes part of the mono framework :/

Comment: I did a bit of searching and there are a few old messages floating around about razor being included and that it should work, but razor working is of course not the same as MVC3 projects in monodevelop working, yet. Thanks a lot for the effort and a good answer!